# How to reliably copy contents of one Azure volume to another on Windows 2008R2 VM

Tags: azure

I have an Azure VM with two additional volumes - F: and G: for sake of discussion.

On F I have files from an installed third party application - binaries, dependencies, SQL databases.

My plan right now is to shut down the server, and detach and attach both volumes to an entirely different VM.  Then copy the contents from F to G.  Then remount the G drive on the original VM as F.

Both drives are on different VHDs

Can someone suggest a cleaner / more reliable way of doing this?

Comment: Are F and G on different VHDs?

Comment: yes they are both using different VHDs

Comment: Can you Detach the Disk/VHD containing F:, do a CopyBlob to another VHD (which would be your G:) and then reattach one of the VHDs back to your VM?

Comment: Or just detach the disks from the current VM, mount them to another one, move the files, detach again and attach only one of the disks. I just don't see the point of detaching the disks instead of moving the files using the current VM and detaching F to later change G to F.